# Sorting column A based on a column B which contains previous values from column A

Tags: sql, sorting, plsql, lag, lead

I'd like to sort column A based on a column B which contains previous values from column A.

This is what I have:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| ID |    A     |    B     |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | 17209061 |          |
|  2 | 53199491 | 51249612 |
|  3 | 61249612 | 17209061 |
|  4 | 51249612 | 61249612 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

And this is what I'd like to have:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| ID |    A     |    B     | Sort_seq |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 17209061 |          |        1 |
|  3 | 61249612 | 17209061 |        2 |
|  4 | 51249612 | 61249612 |        3 |
|  2 | 53199491 | 51249612 |        4 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have `id` and `sort_seq` backwards.

Comment: It's how it should be. ID from the first table has nothing to do with sorting sequence. I need to sort it the right way to get last ID, which should be 2.

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The `id` is needed to define what "previous value" means.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lag()` in `order by`:

```
order by lag(a) over (order by id) nulls first
```

If you want a column, then:

```
select t.id, t.a, t.prev_a,
       row_number() over (order by prev_a nulls first)
from (select t.*, lag(a) over (order by id) as prev_a
      from t
     ) t;
```